# secondary location block will not respond with "try_files"

Tags: nginx

I have two reactjs apps on the same server, the second one is a client based PDF renderer and i'm attempting to get it to respond whenever anything under the `/pdf/*` namespace gets called

(testing on local before using the config in production)

```
server {
    listen       8080;

    ## Exact Match /pdf
    location = /pdf {
      root /Users/aronlilland/Documents/dev/backbone-ui/applications/pdf-renderer/build;
      add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    ## Match anything /pdf/*
    location /pdf {
      root /Users/aronlilland/Documents/dev/backbone-ui/applications/pdf-renderer/build;
      add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
 
    ## Everything else
    location / {
      root /Users/aronlilland/Documents/dev/backbone-ui/applications/backbone/dist;
      add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
  }
```

I know the location syntax is correct, because if i replace the contents with a text blurb I can confirm `/pdf` responds independently of everything under the `/` location block.

to test this I used the following under each `/pdf` block

```
location /pdf {
  add_header Content-Type "text/plain";
  return 200 "success pdf*";
}

location = /pdf {
  add_header Content-Type "text/plain";
  return 200 "success pdf only";
}
```

something changes though when `try_files` and `root` are added in the `/pdf` blocks, then it falls back to the `/` block instead

any ideas on how I can tweak my config to get the second pdf renderer app to respond?

Comment: If you have the wrong value for `root`, the `try_files` statement will send all requests to the `/` block. Specifically, the URL `/index.html` is handled by the `/` block. With your current `root` value, Nginx expects to find the files under `/Users/aron.../build/pdf/` - notice that the URL is also included in the pathname to the files. See [the root directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root)

Answer (score 0):

this was the final (successful) version

```
server {
  ## ...

  ## Match anything prefixed with /pdf/*
  location /pdf {
    root /var/www/backbone-ui/applications/pdf-renderer/build;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    try_files $uri /pdf/index.html;
  }

  ## Everything else
  location / {
    root /var/www/backbone-ui/applications/backbone/dist;
    add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

I had to do some additional changes in the `pdf-renderer` app though, which was an app made using `create-react-app`

I had to make everything in the build folder output to a subfolder called `./build/pdf`. I also had to set a field in `package.json` under the `pdf-renderer` app called `homepage` to `"homepage": "/pdf"`